# Ms Access Get filename with wildcards or loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access Forms and I am trying to open a file but don't know how to open the file based knowing only part of the name. Example below works

```
Private Sub Open_Email_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_cmdExplore_Click
  Dim x As Long
  Dim strFileName As String
  strFileName = "C:\data\office\policy num\20180926 S Sales 112.32.msg"
  strApp = """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Outlook.exe"""
  If InStr(strFileName, " ") > 0 Then strFileName = """" & strFileName & """"
  x = Shell(strApp & " /f " & strFileName)
Exit_cmdExplore_Click:
  Exit Sub

Err_cmdExplore_Click:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume Exit_cmdExplore_Click
End Sub
```

If I change the strFilename to being 
`strFileName = "C:\data\" & Me.Office & "\" & Me.nm & " " & Me.pol & "\" & "*"& " S Sales " & Me.amt & "*" & ".msg"`
It includes the * rather than using it as a wildcard, the date/numbers can be anything or in another format but always eight numbers. I tried using a while loop on the numbers but I am not sure the best way of doing this sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) function to iterate over all files that match a string pattern.

```
strApp = """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Outlook.exe""" 
Dim strFilePattern As String
strFilePattern ="C:\data\" & Me.Office & "\" & Me.nm & " " & Me.pol & "\" & "*"& " S Sales " & Me.amt & "*" & ".msg"

Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Dir(strFilePattern)
Do While Not strFileName = vbNullString
    If InStr(strFileName, " ") > 0 Then strFileName = """" & strFileName & """" 
    x = Shell(strApp & " /f " & strFileName) 
    strFileName = Dir
Loop
```

The first call to `Dir` with the pattern as a parameter will find the first file that matches the pattern supplied. All subsequent calls without the pattern will return the next file that matches the pattern.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. But still, probably something like `Shell(QUOTE & fileName & QUOTE)` would look better I guess. And declaring `QUOTE` as constant.

Comment: I tried this but asks for expected end of statement error so I removed dim from strFilePattern and StrFileName  and nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @New2Programming Sorry, sloppy error there. Are you sure the pattern is valid? You can debug.print strFilePattern and verify files that match this pattern exist

Comment: I just tried debug and it shows as * S Sales 112.31*.msg instead of the numbers

Comment: I assume that's a fully valid path, not just a filename?

Comment: Please ignore me it does work I noticed I needed to add another wildecard as the pattern on some files are different now getting a cant open msg so need to look into this . many thanks.

Comment: Sorry just noticed debug still shows the * wildcards? is this correct? Thanks

Comment: `strFilePattern` should show the wildcards, `strFileName` only file names.

Comment: My confusion sorry yes the filename is spot on! Just wish I knew why my msg file wont open guessing its trying to open it twice or something. thanks for al your help and sticking with me.

Answer (score 1):

So, lets rebuild the question a bit. Imagine that you are having the following 5 files in a given folder:

- A:\peter.msg
- A:\bstack.msg
- A:\coverflow.msg
- A:\heter.msg
- A:\beter.msg

and you need to find the files, that correspond to `"A:\*eter.msg"` and print them.
For this, you need to use the keyword `Like`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim someNames As Variant
    someNames = Array("A:\peter.msg", "A:\bstack.msg", _
                "A:\coverflow.msg", "A:\heter.msg", "A:\beter.msg")

    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = LBound(someNames) To UBound(someNames)
        If someNames(cnt) Like "A:\*eter.msg" Then
            Debug.Print someNames(cnt)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)